# How can I improve my answer?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality, down-votes

Few days ago I answered a question. It had been downvoted. So, I just deleted it. However, today I am feeling curious (so I undeleted it). Can anyone please check and let me know what is wrong with [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/620368/1) (original revision, updated answer is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/620368/206574)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, consider the fact that only one person downvoted. As a general rule, you shouldn't read too much into solitary downvotes. That said, I can see some problems with your answer:

1. It is just a command. There is no explanation of what this is, or what it is supposed to be doing.
2. `inxi` isn't installed by default, so it is very likely not to be present in the target machine.
3. As far as I know, `inxi` is a Linux thing (although [there seems to be](https://github.com/smxi/inxi) some limited BSD support as well), so it isn't very portable.
4. In addition to the above limitations of `inxi`, the only thing that `inxi -S` would give that isn't already provided by the `uname -a` command mentioned in the top answer is the name of the Desktop environment, which is very unlikely to be relevant given that the question was about sshing to a new machine. So even in the case where `inxi` is available, there's very little benefit over the very portable `uname -a`.

Comment: I have updated the answer as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

A downvote does not mean the answer is wrong.  It just means someone was willing to spend a few reputation points to give it a lower priority, for whatever reason. (On the flip side of that is that an upvoted answer does not need to be correct, but that's another story).

As for the answer: You just show a command an its output. What is `inxi`? Where can one find it? Is it only for Linux (what distributions?) or does it work on BSD systems and other Unices too? (the question mentions "Unix/Linux", possibly indicating that they are interested in non-Linux systems too)  Is it likely that it is installed, or can easily be installed, on a random client's system that the user in the question is accessing?  Why do you suggest the `-S` option specifically?  Is the output that you show self explanatory, or does it need a bit of explanation?

Those are just a few things you could address to make it a fuller answer.

Also, as this is an old question with a very upvoted accepted answer, you may want to address the benefits of your approach over the approach in the accepted answer (if there were none, why answer?)

Comment: I have updated the answer as per your suggestion.

Comment: @blueray The answer looks really good now.

Comment: You could extend the argument to  "not even the accepted answer need to be correct" ... but again, another story ;)